# Can't show bootstrap modal popup in wordpress page or widgets

Tags: mysql, wordpress, bootstrap-modal

Below is code for running bootstrap modal popup on button click when i run this source code in default wordpress theme it will gives proper output, but when i run same code in another theme(purchased theme) it will not shown popup on click.
Is there any bootstrap,js link issue or another issue plz suggest me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>  meta charset="utf-8">  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, nitial-scale=1">  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.5-ist/css/bootstrap.min.css">  <script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>  <script rc="bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script></head><body><div class="container">  <h2>Modal Example</h2>  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>  <!-- Modal -->  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>  </div></div></body></html>
```

Comment: check browser console log for errors

Comment: it should be bootsrap.js and bootsrap.css. check that css and js included?